# Invalid latitude value: must be between -90 and 90

Tags: javascript, phonegap, azure-maps

I'm trying to create a map by javascript Azure Map in my phonegap app, but it gives the following error:

> atlas.min.js?api-version=1.0:362 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid LngLat 
>   latitude value: must be between -90 and 90

And my code:

```
 var map = new atlas.Map("task-map-view", {
        "subscription-key": MapsAccountKey,
        center: [39.749434, -104.930420],
        zoom: 8
    });
```

any suggestions?

Comment: `center: [-104.930420, 39.749434],`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I come from using mapquest and obviate the possibility that Azure inverted the values. Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you have reversed your latitude and longitude values. Note that Azure maps coordinates are represented as [longitude, latitude].

If you are curious as to why, longitude is equivalent to x and latitude to y, thus [x, y]

Comment: Thanks for replying I had already resolved thanks to @Chris G's comment. Thank you anyway

Comment: that fixed it for me. for some reason mapbox uses longitude-latitude order -.-a this is going to be annoying

Comment: Most GIS platforms use longitude/latitude. Google and Bing went against this standard with their public maps for some odd reason.